# Подскажите как сбросить пароль администратора через Mysql. Сайт сделано на CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Забыл логин и пароль от админки, помогите пожалуйста как восстановить логин пароль от админки через базу данных, сайт разработан на CodeIgniter.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Документация утверждает следующее: *CodeIgniter has a config file that lets you store your database connection values (username, password, database name, etc.). The config file is located at application/config/database.php.* Так что просто посмотрите содержимое этого файла.

Comment: и это поможет изменить изменить логин пароль? 
забыл логин и пароль от админки , хочу сбросить и заного создать ...

Comment: "application/config/database.php" здесь все правильно

Comment: Ну там у Вас есть пользователь, имеющий полный доступ к БД. От его имени Вы можете выполнить на базе что угодно, изменить любые данные.

Comment: Ну и в качестве довеска: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-49654.html